# Screen dim buttons not working on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: kernel, screen

Since I have upgraded from the last 11.10 to 12.04 the screen dim buttons ceased to function. As I see this is due to the replacement of the 3.0 kernel with the 3.2 starting the system with the 3.0.19 kernel screen dim works.

Anyone having similar experience?

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Same problem on a toshiba portege.

Answer (score 0):

This script will automatically applies toshiba-acpi patch to your kernel.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:keks9n/main`

Update it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install,

```
sudo apt-get install toshiba-acpi-fix
```

Check Settings

```
sudo toshset -q
```

for list of Toshiba settings

```
sudo toshset
```

I guess this will help you, I got the controls back using **Fn** key.